# Google cloud function python cannot interact with blobs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to upload a file to a bucket, parse into a json and insert it into a table in bigquery. I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'blob'
```

I believe it is a depndency issue but I don't know how to solve it.

I am coding directly into the cloud function gui.

```
def create_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    print(f"********The file {file['name']} was created in {file['bucket']} at {event['timeCreated']}")
    
    
    bucket = file['bucket']
    blob = bucket.get_blob(file['name'])
    data = blob.download_as_string()
    table_id="tableid"
    client=bigquery.Client()
    client.insert_rows_json(table_id,[data])
    print(blob)
```

Comment: Is this the same code that generated that error? I don't see anything that would have created it. Can you include the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first create a storage Client object and the call the  `get_blob` function.

[Blobs / Objects](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html)

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(file['bucket'])
blob = bucket.get_blob(file['name'])
```